# Cannot read property 'enqueueSetState' of undefined in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm not quite sure why I'm getting this error.

```
class ContentProcessing extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {content: currentData};
        this.setData = this.setData.bind(this);
    }

    setData(data) {
        this.setState({
            content: data
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <div>
                    <Card title={this.state.content} />
                </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The error is reported at

```
    this.setState({
        content: data
    });
```

Basically I'm launching setData from a Button in another class, as soon as I click it my page breaks and I receive the error.

I checked and it looks like in setData(), `this.state` is undefined so I suppose that's probably where the problem comes from.

I've looked at a few other answers that were having this same problem but their fixes don't seem to be working for me.

Comment: You're not using `this.state` in setData()?

Comment: I'm not because I can't, I need to use this.stestate or it won't actually change this.state

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong with the code you've posted here. You need to post how you're creating the component and calling setData function, maybe we can help you then

Answer (score 3):

This error is because this.setState in not bind to this in main class. If you want to pass setState to somewhere else you need to bind it first in its main class:

```
class ContentProcessing extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {content: currentData};
    this.setData = this.setData.bind(this);
    this.setState = this.setState.bind(this); // <- try by adding this line
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your constructor you have:

```
this.state = {content: currentData};
```

Where does **currentData** come from? If it's supposed to be passed as a prop, then change that line to:

```
this.state = {content: prop.currentData};
```

Comment: It's not a prop. It's just the default information I want loaded when the page loads. That works, I don't think it's what causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are calling setData from Card component.

If this is the case, send setData as a prop to Card component

```
// Below code snippet in ContentProcessing component
<div>
  <Card
    title={this.state.content}
    setData={this.setData}
  />
</div>
```

Now you can access setData method in Card component as prop.

```
// Call it in Card component
this.props.setData(data);
```

Comment: I'm already able to access it, it's just that if I launch setData it gives me an error and I can't understand why

Comment: edited to make more clear the actual problem, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

This setData is useless as it will just stay `undefined` all the time

```
setData(data) {
        this.setState({
            content: data
        });
    }
```

You can some sort of `event` which will be responsible for `setState()` Something like :

```
   render() {
        return (
                <div>
                    <Card title={this.state.content} onClick={() => {this.setData}}/>
                </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I am already calling setData from another class, the problem happens when I do launch it.

Comment: I can't see anywhere calling setData in the above code  ?

Comment: I didn't post it. It's not really important since that part is working fine. I'm basically doing what you posted.